# How can I set a QTextEdit to indent like a terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qtextedit

I wish to indent my text according to the amount of characters there is ( the same was a terminal works on Linux / Mac) rather than the width of each individual letter ( the way text editors / HTML usually handle it)

My goal is to be able to indent using spaces as I have a logger that is already configured for console and file output, this would allow me to use the already existing indentation system without having to create one using HTML / CSS

Edit : here is a photo to try and clarify what I am trying to achieve, the screen comes from the output I wish to use ( color is a bonus but not vital ). As you can see everything is lined up.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you mean. Can you try to be more clear, and possibly provide a graphical representation of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Not sure but it sounds like you just want a fixed width (rather than proportionally spaced) font.  Maybe?

Comment: I added a picture for clarity. @G.M. I did not even consider that, I will give it a try it does seem like a simple solution

Answer (score 0):

In the end the solution I used is the `kbd` html tag such as seen [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_kbd.asp).

My understanding is that it's a tag that applies default monospace font to the text inside of it. In any case it yields the output I was trying to get.